# How can I tell what auth methods a server supports?

Tags: ssh, authentication, password, dsa

I'm trying to ssh to a box using a dsa key. I'm prompted for my pass-phrase, but then it defaults to using password authentication. Seems like it would do this if the first authentication failed, but there is not mention of this, and I've done this on lots of other servers time and time again - now with this new server it has just become a problem

How can I tell what auth methods a server supports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run ssh -v then in the output you'll find a line like:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

which details what are the options supported by the server.

Comment: Add multiple -v options, e.g. -vv, -vvv for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about Windows but if you are going from a Linux system then ssh -v will list the authentication methods that are cycled through as you make your connection.